# Bootstrap multiselect is not working when i bind the data from response in Angularjs

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, bootstrap-multiselect

Bootstrap multiselect is not working when i bind the data from response in Angularjs

```js
angular.module('ngvalueSelect', [])
 .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope','$http', function($scope,$http) {
   $http.get('https://reqres.in/api/unknown')
  .then(function (result) {
      console.log(result.data);
      $scope.exampleData  = result.data;
      $scope.data = result.data;
  })
   $scope.data = {
    availableOptions: [
         {value: '001', name: 'Hello'},
         {value: '002', name: 'integer'},
       
    ]
   };
   console.log( $scope.data );
}]);
```

```html
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u"
        crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp"
        crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.15/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css"
        type="text/css" />

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.15/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="mj.js"></script>

</head>

<body ng-app="ngvalueSelect">

    <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
        <form name="myForm">
            <label for="ngvalueselect"> ngvalue select: </label>
            <select size="6" name="ngvalueselect" ng-model="data.model" id="multiselect" multiple="multiple">
                <option ng-repeat="option in data.availableOptions" ng-value="option.value">{{option.value}}-{{option.name}}</option>
            </select>
        </form>
        <hr>
        <pre>model = {{data.model | json}}</pre>
        <br/>
        <form name="myForm">
                <label for="ngvalueselect"> ngvalue select: </label>
                <select size="6" name="ngvalueselect" ng-model="data.model" id="multiselect" multiple="multiple">
                <option ng-repeat="option in data.data" ng-value="option.name">{{option.name}}</option>
            </select>
            </form>
            <hr>
            <pre>model = {{data.model | json}}</pre>
            <br/>
    </div>
</body>
<script>
    jQuery(function () {
        jQuery('#multiselect').multiselect();
    });
</script>

</html>
```

Both the JSON are of the same format, but when i hard code the values availableOptions it's working fine. When i get the values from the response it's not working. Any fixes, please help me. TIA. Even i tried multiple tag for select box but i'm not getting dropdown.It's showing all values directly

Comment: you should use `ng-if="data.result1"` inside select tag, so select will be rendered after you get result.

Comment: @RajeevRanjan Tried that too but didn't work. It's loading all the values in one go . I'm not getting any dropdown and checkbox

Comment: Can you try `ng-if="data.model"`

Comment: @RajeevRanjan I posted a dummy response can you please fix that, so i can get a dropdown as the above one to select. Yeah i tried `data.model` didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution using semantic-ui. Finally, It worked out.

```js
angular.module('ngvalueSelect', [])
 .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope','$http', function($scope,$http) {
   $http.get('https://reqres.in/api/unknown')
  .then(function (result) {
      console.log(result.data);
      $scope.exampleData  = result.data;
      $scope.data = result.data;
  })
}]);
```

```html
<html>

<head>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.1.8/semantic.min.css" >
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-beta1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.1.8/semantic.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="mj.js"></script>



</head>
<body ng-app="ngvalueSelect">

        <div ng-controller="ExampleController">

        <select name="skills" multiple="" class="ui fluid dropdown">
                <option value="">Skills</option>
               <option ng-repeat="option in data.data" ng-value="option.name">{{option.name}}</option>

              </select>
</body>
<script>
 $('.ui.fluid.dropdown')
 .dropdown({
   maxSelections: 5
 })
;
  
</script>

</html>
```