# How can I make a multiselect dropdown not in HTML. It needs to be in good UI

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm very new to coding and
I'm trying to make a good looking multi select drop down.

```
<select multiple>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! Would you be so kind to explain your problem in greater detail. Right now it's not clear what your are asking. Thank you and good luck!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bootstrap 4 multiselect dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50895806/bootstrap-4-multiselect-dropdown)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in many ways, one is using semantic ui. Add this script file

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.1.8/semantic.min.css" >
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-beta1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.1.8/semantic.min.js"></script>

<script>
$('.ui.fluid.dropdown')
.dropdown({
maxSelections: 5
}) 
</script>

 <select  class="ui fluid dropdown">
            <option value="">Skills</option>
 </select>
```

For better understanding please go through this example [Bootstrap multiselect is not working when i bind the data from response in Angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50327329/bootstrap-multiselect-is-not-working-when-i-bind-the-data-from-response-in-angul)

If you want in Bootstrap4 please have a look at this [Bootstrap 4 multiselect dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50895806/bootstrap-4-multiselect-dropdown)